# How to call a common function after two separate functions called in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns

Hi I have a two functions like

1. markPaymentPaidWithCreditCard(String cardNumber, Long amount)
2. markPaymentPaidWithCash(Long amount)

Now if any of these functions executed I need to call sendSMS() function which design pattern should I use and what is best possible way to achieve this.

Comment: You can use AOP for this.

Comment: Just call `sendSMS()` in both of them. Seriously, this is way too little information to provide any meaningful patterns. Also, don't look for patterns where they might not be needed - i.e. unless calling `sendSMS()` in each of those methods is a problem, do the simple thing. If it is a problem then please state why and any constraints you have.

Comment: @Thomas I can't call the same method in both as suppose if add new method then at time developer will be responsible to call the function and if he/she misses then this sendSMS won't be send

Comment: please provide the code in which you are calling those methods. Is there anything specific? The easiest and most clear would be just to add a call to sendSMS() method whenever its needed

Answer (score 0):

As most of the developers pointed out it's really easy just to add sendSMS method in individual methods.

Reason being we are adding layers of complexity that can be avoided for the sake of simplicity.

Being said that there's is no alternative to maintaining the list of methods upon which sendSMS will be triggered if you go with AOP's way of doing things.

Another alternative is to use the Observer pattern where in markPaymentPaidWithCreditCard and markPaymentPaidWithCash will be the observers which in turn calls your paymentComplete action.

Pseudocode looks like this:

```
paymentObserver obs

markPaymentPaidWithCreditCard(String cardNumber, Long amount) {
obs.playmentDone()
}

markPaymentPaidWithCash(Long amount){
obs.playmentDone()
}

concrete class Smsservice implements paymentObserver {
void playmentDone(){
// send sms over here
 }
}
```

Which is the same as adding sendSMS method individually in those methods. All in all design pattern makes it look smart by achieving almost the same result.

Hope this helps, Thanks.